# javascript - iterate through array until first occurence of specified element is found?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have an array `["#page1", "yield", "yield", "yield", "#page2", "yield", "#page3" ]`

I want to iterate through the array top-down, starting at the last `yield` and looking for the next occurence of an element not being `yield` (which is `#page2`).

This is what I have:

```
var longest = ["#page1", "yield", "yield", "yield", "#page2", "yield", "#page3" ],
    longestLen = longest.length;
for (i = longestLen-2; i>=0; i--) { 
     if ( longest[i] != "yield") {
          var gotoPage = longest[i];
          }
    }
```

I'm starting at i=5 (6 iterations) and checking if the element is not `yield`. However, the current way runs through all 6 iterations, so I end up with the `page#1` instead of the `#page2`. I don't know how I can stop the iterations.

Using `return` did not work, what other means are there? Is `lastIndexOf` something I could use?

Thanks for help!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're looking for the `break`<sup>[tutorial](http://ilovethecode.com/Javascript/Javascript-Tutorials-How_To-Easy/Exit_a_For_Loop_in_Javascript_with_Break.shtml)</sup> keyword, which breaks out of a loop.

```
if ( longest[i] != "yield") {
    var gotoPage = longest[i];
    break; // wont iterate any further in the for(...) loop
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just because noone mentioned it so far, you can also go with ES5 `.some()` for that.

Looks like:

```
var longest = ["#page1", "yield", "yield", "yield", "#page2", "yield", "#page3" ],
    gotoPage;

longest.reverse().slice(1).some(function( elem ) {
    return (gotoPage = elem) !== "yield";
});

alert('goto page: ' + gotoPage);
```

Comment: Nice solution, but this does not start at the last `yield` does it?

Comment: @pimvdb: since I'm calling `.reverse()` before `.some()` it will!

Comment: But if I run this code I obtain `#page3` for `gotoPage`, because `.some` already stops at `#page3`. Unless I'm mistaking, the OP wants to start at the last `yield`.

Comment: Correct. I can't start at the last entry, because that is the page I'm currently on (on panel-x). "yields" are added to the array when page changes on a correspondig panel (y). In order to get a backward-transition to the proper page, I need to find the last non-"yield" entry on the panel with the currently active page (= #page3).  **break** works fine for me, although I will keep this mind, too

Comment: well, I didn't realize that. If its always 100% sure that you need to skip the very last entry, I extended the snippet with `.slice(1)` which pretty much does the job.

Comment: using it somewhere else. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Try '[break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)' -

```
var longest = ["#page1", "yield", "yield", "yield", "#page2", "yield", "#page3" ],
    longestLen = longest.length;
for (i = longestLen-2; i>=0; i--) { 
     if ( longest[i] != "yield") {
          var gotoPage = longest[i];
          break;
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the 'break' operation with labels, so that you can break out where ever you'd like.

[Javascript Loop Control with Break and Continue](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_loop_control.htm)